# What to do If the request is not completed in a certain time

Tags: python, architecture, fastapi

I am trying to design an API on fastAPI, I have clients who limit the response to their request by time. For example, for some clients it may be tens of seconds, for others milliseconds.

It is assumed that the user sends a request (e.g. /v5/bla/info), the API checks who sends this request and determines the response time for it. If the request is executed during this time, then give an answer, if it is not executed, then at the end of the specified time, give some kind of request ID, so that the user then sends a request to another endpoint (e.g. /v5/check_request), which would give information on the execution (pending, done, error) of the request using the request ID.

The question is how to implement task execution and runtime checking while holding a session with the client

**EDIT** I was thinking that the API would send all requests coming to it to the database, and then some "executor" would take data from the database, execute requests and update the status. meanwhile, the api would check the recording status every n seconds and give the result.
How bad/good is this option. The load is approximately 30 million requests in 24 hours

Comment: I would recommend a setup with celery here. You can basically place the task on the event queue. If it finishes in time then send the response, otherwise you can place the result on a result backend (e.g. Redis) and then retrieve it when the status endpoint is called. You need to configure a result backend in celery so you can check on the status of a task. Are you looking for a code snippet or general advice ?

Comment: thank you for your advice.
any help and suggestions will not be superfluous!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above I would recommend celery. With celery there is the option to schedule long running tasks on a task queue. When you place a task on the queue, a worker can pick up the task and process the computation in a separate process.
Celery can be run in different configurations. You will need to select a broker and a backend. E.g. as a broker RabbitMQ and as a backend Redis. [More Information is here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html).
There is already a cookiecutter [template](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D) for a bigger setup you could use. But you can also build a simpler setup with your own docker-compose file. Once you have configured celery. You can create tasks on the queue with:

```
from celery import Celery


celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "redis://localhost:6379") # or any config you prefer
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", "redis://localhost:6379") # or any config you prefer

@celery.task(name="long_task")
def long_task():
    # long running code
    return True
```

And then add the task with something like this in the first endpoint:

```
task = long_task.delay()
# task.id will give you the id
```

And then second endpoint can call it by id and get the status of the task

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
task_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
```